# How can I hide a tag in a review?

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, ignored-tags

In the *Triage* review queue, I would like the ability to hide certain tags from a post, or automatically skip a post if it has a particular tag.

There could be a relation from my "Ignored Tags" for the queue.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure adding new system functionality is really worthwhile. 
When it's fairly easy to just click the skip button.

More importantly, even though you don't know the technology, tag, or code language etc, you can still *sometimes* determine if it's ok, needs improving, or not salvageable.

The more people who see these the better, as they need to be moderated as quickly as possible for them to be affective.

So I think it's best we get them all, and review the ones we can review, and skip the others.

Comment: Thanks, I actually click skip button. And now I should replace discussion tag to feature tag ?

Comment: If you want to request a new feature, yes.You need to ask for this in your question - explain what you want.